# Radio Button in Oracle APEX 5 with dynamic action

Tags: dynamic, onclick, radio-button, action, oracle-apex-5

I have created a Dynamic Action on a Radio Button "On Click" in Oracle APEX 5.0.

Whenever i click even slightly on the borders of the Radio Group the DA triggers without any options being selected in Radio Button, which is not correct.

Is there any way to fix this without having me to change the DA to "On Change" which is working fine.

Comment: I very much doubt it.  Why would you not change it to fire "on change" when that is what you clearly require?

Comment: @Tony, I have wizard screen with questions in each wizard page. Answers for those questions can be selected from radio button. When a radio button is clicked it moves to next wizard page. If the user wants to see previous question he can still traverse to the previous screen. Issue:  If the DA is on click it moves to next page with same answer chosen previously when clicked. Otherwise he has to change his answer for DA to trigger hence he cannot move to next page unless he changes his answer.

Comment: I see.  You could just add a next page button that can be used in this scenario?  Or make the radio group required so that if the onclick fires with no value selected an error is raised.

Comment: @Tony I tried those, adding button is what my client doesn't want, and making value required won't be right solution. Cuz still we have the problem with radio button.